# Save session from expiring

Tags: jquery, session-timeout

in my web application i am using session for identifing user and for another purpose.
I have read  that set session time as low as u can and refresh it a end of time so  I have set session time out time 5 minute and trying to refresh session after 4 min. For refreshing session I am using a jquery timer (at 200000) that fires well and reset  session value from Cookies. But this don't stop session to expire.

I am firing 4-5 timer from jquery for some other work . My 1 st timer is set for 60000 , 2nd timer is set 8000 , 3rd timer is set 12000. 4 th is above mentioned for session at 200000.

Some time my 1,2 timer fires they give me undefine msg , i have checked it bcause **my session expires**. But i am refreshing my session.

**Beside this it also makes my page inactive when user moves for some other work for some time.**

Comment: please post code or jsFiddle

Comment: @MichaelB. It's not possible t put code bcoz it covers 6-7 pages .If you want I could elaborate my question .

Comment: if you just could isolate the issue related code and post it here, would make it possible for more people to help

Comment: Sorry for bad expalnatin , [Part-1 ]In my project i am using session  , when session is alive everything works good and on session end it gives undefine error.[part-2] In my project i am using jquery timer fr getting new msg , notification and new post . The timer set on this are 1 minute, 1.5 minute ,2 minute. When all this timer go on code behind they have to retrive data on the basis of sessiom. but unfortunately after sometime session expires and this lead undefined msgs. Due to this undefined error my page become inactive. I have traced the reason but don't know how to resolve.